# Track/Log changes to permissions

Tags: 8, users, log-messages

I was trying to find contributed module for Drupal 8 to track practically everything users do on site.

I was able to find some good modules like [Events Log Track](https://www.drupal.org/project/events_log_track) but it only works for entities (Users/Nodes/Taxonomies).

What I would like to do is to be able to track any change with permissions. I know I can track those changes through configuration but I want some additional data like: who changed what and when.

Do you know if there is a contributed module for this?

Should I go custom way? - As I imagine I could hook into any form and track changes from there but I am not sure if it is a right way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen https://www.drupal.org/project/config_log ?

Comment: @Hudri I wonder how I missed that. Thank you!

I will test this one.